# How do I design Mahout code to work on MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I am planning to use LogLikelihoodSimilarity, which is an item based algorithm in Mahout.

But I don't know how to run this algorithm on ***distributed mode***.

Is MapReduce integrated with the algorithm and thus I don't have to write a code for map() and reduce()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce code is autogenerated when you write your programm in Java. You don't have to take care about any map() or reduce() method.

Comment: omg thank you. Why I was wondering for this issue was because Eclipse didn't import packages for MapReduce explicitly even though Mahout auto-generates the MapReduce code.